# How can I make my script do something other than exit if a string doesn't match?

Tags: bash, scripts, dialog

I need help with a loop in my Bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash
trap "" INT TSTP
PASS=10
for i in $(seq 1 100); do     sleep 0.02 ;     echo $i; done | whiptail --title "Login Screen" --gauge "Starting..."  6 60 0
passbox=$(whiptail --title "LOGIN" --passwordbox "Enter password: "  10 60 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)
{
  if [ "$passbox" != "$PASS" ]; then
    for i in $(seq 1 100); do     sleep 0.01 ;     echo $i; done | whiptail --title "LOGIN" --gauge "Unconfirmed..." 6 60 0
    exit 0
  fi
}

for i in $(seq 1 100); do     sleep 0.01 ;     echo $i; done | whiptail --title "LOGIN" --gauge "Confirmed..." 6 60 0
```

The script asks for a password, and if the password is right then it proceeds, but if the password is wrong it exits. How do I keep it open or make it start over when the password is wrong? I want to use this script for my ssh logins.

Comment: That's why someone invented the "while" ;-)

Comment: Use a `while` loop, i.e. if continue the while loop

Comment: i tried but failed,i think it's because of misplaced while,do,done commands.Don't know exactly where do i have to put them.

Comment: If you look at the [bash tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) on [SO] you can see an example of how to make this question clearer, by omitting sections of your script that are not relevant to the problem, and creating a tested example that fails at the same point and for the same reason that your whole script fails. I have no idea what `whiptail` is, but I might understand what is going wrong if you make it more obvious what the script is trying to do.